# Adding a 'Reviews' tab to the product view page removes 'Short Description'

Tags: magento-1.9

I am having problem  with 'Review' tab that I added to our product view page. The tab itself works fine but for some reason my 'Short Description' does not show up anymore.
I added the following code under

```
    <catalog_product_view translate="label"> 
<reference name="content"> 
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

in catalog.xml

```
<block type="review/product_view_list"
 name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_review"
template="review/product/view/list.phtml"> <block type="review/form"
 name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/> </block>
```

and then called it in my product view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_review') ?>
```

'Short Descr' is called in product view.phtml as below:

```
<?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
    <!-- short-description -->
    <div class="short-description">
         <div class="std">
               <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product,$_product->getShortDescription(),'short_description') ?>
         </div>
    </div>
  <?php endif;?>
```

Could someone please point me to the directions as to why 'Short Description' would stop displaying ? As soon as I comment out the code I added in catalog.xml 'Short Descr' comes back.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some js or css is hidding it for you ? product.info is parent block for your reviews block. Any html comming from catalog/product/view.phtml sholud be there if you are seeing your review tab. View source of product view page and Ctrl+f for class="short-description", see if its beein generated.

Comment: Thank you but this is not the case, I checked the source, css & js and nothing there is hiding it. Disabling js & css still did not bring bring the block back. I removed '<?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>' conditional from product view and all it did was place '<div class="short-description">
         <div class="std">
               
         </div>
    </div> ' in product view without the 'Short Description' block inside @maquowicz

Comment: I've tested your code on a clean template. It works just fine. Check your php error-log or Magento system.log aren't producing eny output. Create an override for review/product/view/list.phtml within your template and put some really simple content inside like 'Hello this is a reviews block template'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have used this. It's working

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getDescription()), 'short_description') ?>
```